# how to render still images as a movie

Tags: rendering, animation

i already render my animation as still images i want now make a movie from them i went to video sequence editor and import my images that i already rendered and choose the video format that i want and go all over the settings and now as like a saw in tutorials i need press animation to make a movie from those images

but when i press animation its start rendering as video formart i mean its start the prosess that i already wait about 24 h 
do i miss something here
please help

Answer (score 1):

Something similar happened to me recently, and it wasn't my first animation rendering.

The output directory specification lacked a final backslash; there was an error message about not opening the output file, but I missed it the first few times. After I corrected my output directory to `C:\Animations\` (in my case), rendering went forward properly.